# Solve $x+y+z=3$; $x^3+y^3+z^3=15$; $x^5+y^5+z^5=83$

Tags: systems-of-equations, contest-math, symmetric-polynomials

$$x+y+z=3$$
$$x^3+y^3+z^3=15$$
$$x^5+y^5+z^5=83$$
I spent around 3 hours in solving this equation, but, finally I didn't do it so, I hope you can help me in approaching this problem.

Comment: Isn't from a IMO short or loglist?

Comment: Marking as a dublicat is wrong, since the equations are not the same.

Comment: Coefficients apart, I agree this is not a duplicate: the linked question is about $p_4$, this question is about the solutions $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: Of course the solutions can be found by finding $p_4$, then $p_2$, then $e_1,e_2,e_3$ from $p_1,p_2,p_3$ by Newton's formulas.

Comment: I think it is not so easy, it is from an IMO longlist.

Comment: It looks pretty straightforward anyway: my previous comment clearly gives a roadmap to a complete solution.

Comment: The actual solutions are given by $(1,1-\sqrt{2},1+\sqrt{2})$ and permutations.